# GNU APL -- SAVED with a VERY old SVN version

Tags: apl

I recently installed GNU APL (version 1.7) from source code (configure, make, make install).  Everything is working except I get an error message every time I LOAD a workspace. It gives the same error on Linux Mint 17.3 and on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch).

> WARNING: this workspace was )SAVEd with a VERY old SVN version of GNU APL.
>   Expect problems, in particular when the )SI was not clear.
>   In case of problems, please try )COPY instead of )LOAD.

I didn't see SVN listed as a prerequisite for GNU APL. And, I don't have it installed on either system.

Does anyone know if I need SVN installed or can I just ignore the warning message?

Answer (score 2):

(**Disclaimer**: I do not know much about GNU APL, but a bit about APL etc. - so pls. take the following with a grain of salt ;-))

As I understand the message, it says that the workspace you `)LOAD`ed is rather old (was saved with a old version of GNU APL). That does not say anything about the current version you have and it also does not mean that SVN is required. But as the development of the interpreter progressed, it may have become neccessary to upgrade the binary format in which workspaces are saved. Whilst the developer of the interpreter will most often be able to accommodate and automatically upgrade the format, there might be edge-cases that are not so easy to handle - like when the saved workspace contained a stack (was executing a function) - and the warning should inform you about this. The easiest fix will probably be to )save the workspace again after loading (possibly under a new name - in case you need to access the older version with an older version of GNU APL again - most often these migrations of workspaces will only work forward, but not backward...)

If that is not case (ie coz you saved with a current version) than it is possible that an error (in the interpreter) is involved. Googling that error-text seems to confirm this theory - see http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-apl/2017-01/msg00176.html

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  The only weird thing is I saved it with my current version (1.7) and loaded it with the same version.

Comment: That is weird indeed. Reading the q again and again - but can‘t think of a different explanation - except that there might be a bug involved...

Comment: Pretty sure it is a bug now - seems to be a known one: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-apl/2017-01/msg00176.html

Comment: @MBaas You should fold that comment into your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will sign this up to a bug and live with it.